# Understanding relationship between openssl & mod_ssl

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl, mod-ssl

I am bit confused between openssl & mod_ssl, so after hours of googling & readding documentation i have to post my query here .. 
I am on apache 2 which has ssl inbuilt, so where can i check which openssl version is being used ..
is it the machine's openssl which apache is using or something which comes bundles with mod_ssl

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
$ uname -a
Linux
```

& when i hit the URL it shows following in response :

```
Server:Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.0.e
```

also when grep in mod_ssl.so:

```
$ strings mod_ssl.so | grep -i openssl

OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
```

so why the difference in versions and from where it is picking that version.

Comment: Tell us all the basic information about your system. Also, you should copy and paste instead of typing everything manually.

Comment: I am not Server admin, just web server admin so don't know how & when openSSL was installed on server or who & how installed apache, we are managing the same, so if you can let me know what details you need i can provide the same..

Comment: Well, if the response to the URL whose OpenSSL/1.0.0.e and mod_ssl.so shows the same, then Apache uses this version.

Comment: ok but the one installed in server is OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010 .. so is the fips something else which incorporates 1.0.0.e - http://www.openssl.org/source/ in here fips seems to be something different than others - http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/fipsnotes.html

Answer (score 3):

MOD_SSL is the interface apache uses to communicate with OpenSSL which is a cryptographic engine. OpenSSL does the work, whilst MOD_SSL provides the functions which allow Apache to use OpenSSLs features...

from : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27628939/What-is-the-difference-between-Apache-Mod-SSL-and-OpenSSL.html